# Is this a valid 'main' method of a NSOperation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I am running a `NSOperation` in a separate queue which runs indefinitely and is set up to handle web socket events. 
The events are handled in my `- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message` method in this operation

Is this the correct way to code the main method if this `NSOperation`?

```
- (void)main
{
    [self openSocket];

    while (!self.isCancelled) {
       //
    }
}
```

### Edit

The main purpose of this `NSOperation` is to handle `SocketRocket` messages and send requests.
Handling and processing these events works fine. But how can I make my operation make run indefinitely (without using an empty `while` loop)?

Comment: What is your concern with that code?

Comment: @rmaddy: It looks like a buggy endless loop and the `Energy Impact` indicated by Xcode is `Very High`. Would it make sense to sleep for a couple of milliseconds each cycle?

Comment: That was my concern too. I just wanted to hear yours first. It may not be an issue if there is blocking socket reads in the loop. Otherwise the loop will burn a lot of CPU. Adding calls to `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` would help.

Comment: @rmaddy: `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` helped to reduce the `Energy Impact` to `Low`. Does sleeping (for 0.5 or 1 second) "block" the whole operation and delay the event handling? How can I make sure to handle all events without delay?

Comment: Yes, sleeping blocks the entire thread. So it's not appropriate for time critical code.

Comment: @rmaddy: Is there a better strategy to solve this problem of a endless operation with fast event handling?

Comment: Without knowing the details of what is in the while loop, there's not much more help that can be offered.

Comment: @rmaddy The wile loop is empty. There is nothing in it. I use it to keep the operation alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `NSRunLoop`s are made for. As per [apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1)

> A run loop is an event processing loop that you use to schedule work
>   and coordinate the receipt of incoming events. The purpose of a run
>   loop is to keep your thread busy when there is work to do and put your
>   thread to sleep when there is none.

But... I see from your code that you are using Square's SocketRocket library, by looking in the source code of the library you can find out that [they are already doing this](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.m#L589), so probably you are doing something wrong. You should really expand your question to let us understand what the real problem is, since your SocketRocket object should be ALREADY running and should be ALREADY sending the right notifications when a particular event occurs.

Edit:

From what you said, you simply do NOT need an object that runs indefinitely but rather an object that stays alive as long as your application is alive.

For this you can either use the app delegate, an object being kept alive by the app delegate (aka an app's delegate's property) or a singleton object. Now, for the simplicity sake, i'll use the first example:

in your app's delegate .m file implement the SRWebSocket delegate:

```
@interface SRAppDelegate()<SRWebSocketDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SRWebSocket* socket;

@end

@implementation SRAppDelegate

#pragma mark - SRWebSocketDelegate

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
{

}

#pragma mark - SRWebSocketDelegate optionals

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket
{

}

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean
{

}

@end
```

Then in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method initialize the connection:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:_YOUR_REQUEST_];
    self.socket.delegate = self;
    [self.socket open];
    //Enjoy!
}
```

Now you have a long living connection (as long as your application is alive).

Comment: The solution you describe works fine. I had implemented it previously, but wanted to move the logic into a different class and thought a `NSOperation` would be a better solution.

Comment: there is no need for an NSOperation since the SocketRocket object already manage that for you. What you need is either a singleton of another form of long living object

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on a what kind of long living object I could use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own socket mechanism, you can integrate it into `NSRunLoop` by making a `CFRunLoopSource` out of it.

Just a bit of note when doing that (my usual machine is not with me, so code snippet is largely inaccessible now) you can use `CFEqual` (`-[NSObject isEqual:]`), `CFHash` (`-[NSObject hash]`), `CFCopyDescription` (`-[NSObject description]`), `CFRetain` (`-[NSObject retain]`) and `CFRelease` (`-[NSObject release]`) against any Objective-C objects - consider it like you can toll-free bridge `NSObject` and `CFTypeRef` so you can bridge cast `self` to fill in the `info` (`void *` type which is exactly `CFTypeRef`) and use those functions as callbacks of your `CFRunLoopSource` and here is a quick implementation of the `perform` callback:

```
void _MSCFRunLoopPerformCallback(id self)
{
    [self runOnce];
}
```